# На определенное свойство React не перерисовывает компонент, при использовании метода push()

Tags: reactjs, render

Есть большая форма, в которой куча полей для заполнения. Все работает хорошо, кроме      `values.defects`. При изменении(добавлении записи) методом `push`, `React` не перерисовывает элемент. Хотя значение меняется. Единственный вариант, чтобы заставить его реагировать - это клонирования `values.defects = [...values.defects];`. В этом случае все работает хорошо. Вопрос: что я делаю не так и можно ли сделать без хака.
**React:** 16.8.6
**Formik:** 1.5.1

```
function addDefect() {
    values.defects.push({
        key: values.defect_id,
        part_name: findPart(values.part_id),
        defect_name: findDefect(values.defect_id),
        part_id: values.part_id,
    });
    values.defects = [...values.defects];
    setFieldValue('defects', values.defects);
}
```

**Formik:**

```
const enhancedForm = withFormik({
  enableReinitialize: true,
  mapPropsToValues: props => {
    return {
        //...
        defects: [],
        //...
    };
  },
  isInitialValid: false,
  handleSubmit: (values) => {
    props.onSave(values);
  },
  displayName: 'ComplaintForm',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы устанавливаете новое значение, но react не понимает, что необходимо инициализировать перерисовку компонента, т.к. для него ничего не изменилось. Инициализировать его необходимо, используя `setState`
Читайте подробней про [cостояние и жизненный цикл react компонентов](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

Пример

```js
class Item extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            defects: [],
            input: ''
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
            <form onSubmit={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                let defects = this.state.defects.slice()
                defects.push(this.state.input)
                this.setState({defects, input:''}) //Здесь мы инициализируем перерисовку
            }} >
                <input type="text" 
                  value={this.state.input} 
                  placeholder="укажите дефект" 
                  onChange={(e)=>{
                  this.setState({input: e.currentTarget.value})
                  }}
                />
                <input type="submit" action="submit"/>
            </form >
            <ul>
              {this.state.defects.map((d, index)=>(<li key={index}>{d}</li>))}
            </ul>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }

}


ReactDOM.render(< Item />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```